# Inequality with definite integrals

Tags: integral-inequality

This problem has been bugging me for days. A function $f:[0,\,1]\to[0,\,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ is strictly increasing and differentiable, with $f'$ also strictly increasing. (So $f$ is a convex function.) I want to show that $2\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^2 \, \geqslant \, f\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)$.

I’ve managed so far to show that $f(x)\leqslant x$ for all $0\leqslant x\leqslant1$ and $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\frac12$. I’m stuck after this.

I’ve also shown (if it helps) that $f'(0)\leqslant1\leqslant f'(1)$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of the first $f$ on the RHS?

Comment: If $I=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$, I want to prove that $2I^2\geqslant f(I)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**. $f(x)\le x$

By the mean value theorem, there exist $t\in(0,x)$ and $s\in(x,1)$ such that $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(t)$$ $$\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{1-x}=f'(s)$$
From $t<s$, $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(t)<f'(s)=\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x}$$ so we have $f(x)\le x$.

Let $$I=\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
By step 1, we have $I\le\frac{1}{2}$

**Step 2**. $f(x)\ge f(I)+(x-I)f'(I)$

If $x>I$, there exist some $s\in(I,1)$ that $$\frac{f(x)-f(I)}{x-I}=f'(s)>f'(I)$$ and the result follows.

Same goes for the case $x<I$, since there exist some $t\in(0,I)$ that $$\frac{f(I)-f(x)}{I-x}=f'(t)<f'(I)$$

**Step 3**. $2I^2\ge f(I)$

By step 2,
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge\int_0^1 f(I)+(x-I)f'(I)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=f(I)+(\frac{1}{2}-I)f'(I)\\
&\ge f(I)+(\frac{1}{2}-I)\frac{f(I)}{I}\\
&= \frac{f(I)}{2I}
\end{align}
Thus, $$2I^2\ge f(I)$$

Comment: +1. $f(x)\geq f(I)+(x-I)f'(I)$ also follows because $f$, being convex, lies above the tangent line at $I$.

Comment: +1. Brilliant stuff! Great use of the mean value theorem! I believe you have done a little typo in step 1 after "From $t<s$". Instead of 
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(s)<f'(t)=\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x}$$

It should be:

$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(t)<f'(s)=\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x}$$

Just switch the $t$ and $s$ around.

Comment: @GustavoMontano Corrected. Thanks!